# The method put is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Not quite sure why I am getting this error for the put method. Help would be appreciated.

This code

```
HashMap<ArrayList<String>,ArrayList<Integer>> magicshopitems = new HashMap<ArrayList<String>,ArrayList<Integer>>();
magicshopitems.put("items", itemlist);
magicshopitems.put("amount", itemlistamount);
```

produces

```
The method put(ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<Integer>) in the type HashMap<ArrayList<String>,ArrayList<Integer>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, ArrayList<String>)
```

Comment: A `String` is not an `ArrayList<String>`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to put a String into an ArrayList.

You need to put the String into a list first;

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("items");

magicshopitems.put(list, itemlist);
```

**Side Note**:

It is better practice to use the parent interface classes when constrcuting such a collection.

**Instead of**:

```
HashMap<ArrayList<String>,ArrayList<Integer>> magicshopitems = 
    new HashMap<ArrayList<String>,ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

**You could have**:

```
Map<List<String>, List<Integer>> magicshopitems = 
    new HashMap<List<String>, List<Integer>>();
```

Comment: Or more likely, change the hashmap to `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>`

Comment: Thanks, the issue is all sorted out now, appreciate the help.